# Example of SOA model in real world

Tags: architecture, soa

would you please show me a SOA model in real world?(Service Provider,Service Broker,Service Requester)
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is difficult to show you examples of real world. But here is an some of the articles I have written to show such integration using ESB and BPS.

http://wso2.org/library/articles/2011/04/integrate-rules-soa

http://wso2.org/library/articles/2011/06/securing-web-service-integration

http://wso2.org/library/articles/2011/05/integrate-business-rules-bpel